# Should Keys be INDICES or compound PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql

I have a schema with a parent and child table.
A parent record, may have many children (1 to many)
To link these, a third table has the PRIMARY KEY of the parent, and child records.
Should this linking table, have a compound PRIMARY KEY?
Or, should this simply be two FOREIGN KEYS, each with an INDEX()?

```
CREATE TABLE parent(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

So, should the linking table be like..

```
CREATE TABLE parent_child_link(
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  child_id INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX(parent_id),
  INDEX(child_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES child(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Or should this be

```
CREATE TABLE parent_child_link(
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  child_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(parent_id, child_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its one to many and not many to many, adding a `parent_id` to the child table is sufficient.

Comment: While I assume you've simplified the example given, there may be cases where parent and child can be the same table. This depends significantly how your application treats these two people types. In this case the answer still holds.